# Style change every second mapped element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dictionary, styled-components

I have a question - how can I change background color of  component every second time when I map through  component? Should I condition it from "i" variable in some way..? Or maybe if/else condition when returning something from the map function? Is there any cleaner way to do so? I use styled-components for styling most of my elements, but I want to change the backgroundColor every second item.

```
const Tree = memo(({ children, name, style, defaultOpen = false }) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(defaultOpen)
  const previous = usePrevious(isOpen)
  const [bind, { height: viewHeight }] = useMeasure()
  const { height, opacity, transform } = useSpring({
    from: { height: 0, opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(20px,0,0)' },
    to: { height: isOpen ? viewHeight : 0, opacity: isOpen ? 1 : 0, transform: `translate3d(${isOpen ? 0 : 20}px,0,0)` }
  })
  const Icon = Icons[`${children ? (isOpen ? 'Minus' : 'Plus') : 'Close'}SquareO`]
  return (
    <Frame>
      <Icon style={{ ...toggle, opacity: children ? 1 : 0.3 }} onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)} />
      <Title style={style}>{name}</Title>
      <Content style={{ opacity, height: isOpen && previous === isOpen ? 'auto' : height }}>
        <a.div style={{ transform }} {...bind} children={children} />
      </Content>
    </Frame>
  )
})

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Global />
    {data.map((info, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <Tree name={info.name} defaultOpen>
            {info.division.map((divi, idx) => (
              <Tree name={divi.title}>
                {divi.nonITteams.map((nonITteam) => {
                  return <li>{nonITteam}</li>
                })}
                {divi.teams.map((team) => {
                  return (
                    <Tree name={team.name}>
                      {team.members.map((member) => {
                        return <li>{member}</li>
                      })}
                    </Tree>
                  )
                })}
              </Tree>
            ))}
          </Tree>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to get every second item you can use

`(i + 1) % 2 === 0`

on the first run 
**i is 0** 
so: `(0 + 1) % 2 === 0` will return `false`
but for second run 
**i is 1**
so: `(1 + 1) % 2 === 0` will return `true`

---

if you can you can use css `:nth-child(2n)` 
with this selector you can apply style to every 2th child
check here: [nth-child(n) MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

### update

```
                {data.map((info, i) => {
                    <div key={i} style={i % 2 === 0 ? { backgroundColor: "blue" } : {}} />
                })}
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but it was returning everything blue, even with an else statement without the styling. Should I use the condition elsewhere?

 {data.map((info, i) => {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        return (
          <div key={i} style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}}>